# Choisir entre « dans » et « à »

Tags: sens, usage, prépositions

Comment savoir quel mot choisir entre *dans* et *à* ?

Par exemple, faut-il écrire

> Je suis rentré à mon pays

ou

> Je suis arrivé dans mon pays

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si la question est bien à propos du choix d'utilisation des prépositions *à* et *dans*, cela dépend essentiellement du verbe d'action utilisé.

Dans ton exemple, **« Je suis [... *action* ...] [... *préposition*... ] mon pays. »**, le choix de la préposition dépendra donc du verbe choisi. Quelques exemples :

- Je suis retourné *dans* mon pays. (idem pour rentrer / arriver)
- Je suis attaché *à* mon pays.
- Je suis venu *de* mon pays.
- Je suis passé *par* mon pays.
- ...

Il n'y a pas de règle globale, chaque verbe possède un certain nombre de variantes de sens en fonction des prépositions qu'on peut y associer.
Pour résoudre toutes ces questions, il n'y a, me semble-t-il, pas de voie facile sans pratiquer la langue pour rencontrer fréquemment ses usages.